# Using a question as a FAQ index for a topic

Tags: discussion

At our company, we have an internal tenant for SoF and we use it for company wide programming/software related questions, answers and discussion.

Over the last year, our team has been using it for a security compliance initiative being driven for improving our cloud security posture across the organisation (we post commonly encountered questions and answers from email support and also encourage users to do the same).

To further assist users, we also created a 'master' question to serve as a 'FAQ-index' in a manner very similar to this: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

A couple of us driving the initiative 'maintain' the FAQ-index and ensure that it is organized/grouped by high level areas for easy reference and we guide new users to start on that page to get a quick handle on some common queries they may face and the resolutions.

My question is, is this approach considered a violation of Stack Exchange/SoF norms? If so, exactly what problem does it create? Are there any alternate options available to get the same effect?

Comment: What is *"an internal tenant for SoF"*?

Answer (score 1):

Well, MSE and the community managers use it that way - and there's a few situations where this "format" of question (The community FAQ) works well. I'd say it fits into the broader context of "being a place to *find* answers" rather than being a place to ask questions.

I've *personally* used a community FAQ to act as [both a general answer and a signpost to other posts](https://superuser.com/questions/709913/how-do-i-identify-hardware-i-am-unfamiliar-with-on-my-computer)

At the end of the day, Q&A is a tool, and an *internal instance* is going to have different needs than one serving a wider audience.

To me, in an internal Q&A, master questions/community FAQs are something that's 'easier' to manage than on a public site like MSE or Super User and used appropriately is a very useful thing to have in your toolbox.